# Expo typescript template shows the errors related to JSX like "Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'View'. 5:10:5 typescript2322"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, expo

I am new for Expo and trying to start from typescript template via `npx create-expo-app -t expo-template-blank-typescript` command, but stuck on the JSX type errors shown below although Expo can start server normally.

[JSX type errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oES8G.png)

Here is the default package.json and tsconfig.json craeted as template.

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YR1y.png)

[tsconfig.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7uk1.png)

I tried to change/add some entries on these files for troubleshooting found in the web (e.g. downgraded @types/react version to version 17, tried several "jsx" options in tsconfig.json, etc.), but none of them did not work for me unfortunately.

Appreciated if someone has some idea for solution or troubleshooting.

- `tsc` command produced a lot of errors such as 'Cannot use JSX unless the '--jsx' flag is provided.'
- I am using nvim as text editor, but the same error appears in vscode as well.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Changing filetype for `*.tsx` file from `typescript` to `typescriptreact` at nvim config resolved the issue.